# Layout issue in Interface Builder XCode 8.3

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder, constraints

I have this weird issue in interface builder. When I place a `UILabel` in a `UIView` and drag it to the leading/trailing end of its superview I'm not seeing any blue line (which is usually 8 points from the edge).

I tried to find if there's an option in Editor menu to reset it but no luck.
Anyone faced the same issue and resolved it?[image]

Comment: Editor > Canvas > Show constraints (toggle this to unchecked)

Comment: @SaurabhJain I tried that but still couldn't see the edge line while dragging the label.

Comment: Go in Menu' Editor->Canvas and make sure the option "Show bounds Rectangles" or "Show Layout Rectangles" is enable.

Comment: @SaurabhJain No that's not what the problem is. Those options just shows the bounds and layout borders of the views. The problem is when I drag a label to the end of the superview it's not suggesting the 8point spacing constraint.

Comment: press alt key and hover mouse over it.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: @SaurabhJain No. alt + hovering just shows the spacing points the view has. I don't know if you understood the exact issue here.

Comment: @SaurabhJain I have updated the post with a gif. Please have a look.

Comment: ok.. got it.. May be this X-Code issue restart your x-code and check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by enabling Snap to Guides from Editor menu.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go :]

The problem is that Xcode is an IDE with quite a lot of bugs. They are usually very small, but sometimes very annoying.
I always restart Xcode from time to time.
And when something isn't working, as it should, restart of Xcode solves this problem in 99% of cases.

**So, try to restart Xcode. Hope it will help.**

Comment: That didn't work either. I even restarted my mac and deleted derived data content, but still the same issue.

Comment: Solved it. Snap to Guides is the culprit.